# Can anyone identify this sword?

Tags: social-history, weapons, sword

It's been around for years in the attic and I would love to find out where it's from. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Name it? Er, Jim...call it Jim...Jim, the Cavalry Sabre.

Comment: It would be useful if you could give dimensions.

Comment: "It's been around for years in the attic." Why might it have historical significance. Is one of the users, perhaps a member of your family famous? Or at least was it "known" to have been used on a famous battle?

Comment: Very similar to my Dad's air force saber....

Comment: I agree with Lars, dimensions may be crucial to identify this item.

Comment: Could be an infantry officer's sword or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a cutlass or klewang to me. I can't see the actual length, but it seems too short for a cavalry sabre. Unless there were pony regiments somewhere. ;-)

Google on 'Dutch Marechaussee klewang'. They seem quite similar, but no fancy decorated blades, with a different point. Otherwise, very close.